# Ampersand causing issues in Google Sheets Formula

Tags: google-sheets

I was trying to use the hyperlink formula to create an automatic e-mail creation, however, when i try to pull an information that has Ampersand in it the formula doesn't end.

[image: Hyperlink formula]

[image]

Note that the formula should bring the full name (Research & Innovation) but it stops at Research.

Would you have any suggestion for me to try to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument of the HYPERLINK function is not well constructed as it includes a semicolon `;` before the question mark `?` and an ampersand `&` after the question mark `?` and the ampersand  `&` on cell A7's value is not escaped. Replace it with `%26`

Reference

- [Escaping ampersand in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16622504/1595451)
- [mailto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto)

Comment: I've opted to use a minimalist example, thanks for your suggestions, i ended up using a different model with your example and it worked just fine:
**Substitute(AQ9;"&";"%26")**
In this case, any line in column AQ that in my case brings the Description that could have Ampersand, would have it changed and pulled correctly in the formula.
Thank you very much.